# how to check the fields of schema are of type array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, scala, apache-spark

current code is :

```
schema.fields.foreach(f => {
                            // check if schema field is type of array 
                            // if yes then throw array not supported 
                             if (f.dataType.typeName == "array") {
 throw ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException(s"${f.name} column is ArrayType, " +
                                  "writing arrays to CSV isn't supported. Please convert this column to a different data type.")
                             }
                            })
```

But now I want such case , if schema.field.typeName is of string array or array of strings then String array should be converted to a comma separated String. and if its not string array then throw array not accepted exception. In short- I want to support only string array and not others if anything comes apart from string array then I want to pass below exception

```
throw ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException(s"${f.name} column is ArrayType, " +
                                      "writing arrays to CSV isn't supported. Please convert this column to a different data type.")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to drill down further on the array type and check the element type. The following code can do this :

```
if (f.dataType == ArrayType) {
val arrayType = f.dataType.asInstanceOf[ArrayType]

if (arrayType.elementType == StringType) {
 throw ArrayDataTypeNotSupportedException(s"${f.name} column is ArrayType, " +
                                  "writing arrays to CSV isn't supported. Please convert this column to a different data type.")
                          }
}
```